# How to re-use my x-amazon-apigateway-integration definition throughout Swagger YAML document?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, swagger, openapi

I am currently using Swagger to define an API with many end-points, and each one of those end-points all have the same definition for the 'x-amazon-apigateway-integration' key. I would like to define this somewhere in the document, and re-use that definition through-out.

Either I am not understanding how the definition should be defined, I am not placing it in the correct location or a mix of the two. I have tried defining this definition within 'definitions', and as some alias under it's own key. The definition (with key information removed) is:

```
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
  responses:
    default:
      statusCode: '200'
  passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
  httpMethod: POST
  uri: >-
    arn:aws:apigateway:<region>:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/<lambda arn>/invocations
  credentials: '<role arn>'
  type: aws     
  requestTemplates: "application/json": "<object definition>"
```

I have tried defining this as an alias under it's own key (not definitions, but the same base scope):

```
amazon:
  Amazon: &Amazon
    - responses:
        default:
          statusCode: '200'
    - passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
    - httpMethod: POST
    - uri: >-
    arn:aws:apigateway:<region>:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/<lambda arn>/invocations
    - credentials: '<role arn>'
    - type: aws     
    - requestTemplates:
      "application/json": "<object definition>"
```

To use, I have the following:

```
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
  *Amazon
```

The error received on API Gateway import is 'Unable to parse API definition because of a malformed integration at path /'

I have also tried defining this under 'definitions', and using 'ref' to access it:

```
definitions:
  Amazon:
    type: object
    x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
      responses:
        default:
          statusCode: '200'
      passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
      httpMethod: POST
      uri: >-
          arn:aws:apigateway:<region>:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/<lambda arn>/invocations
      credentials: '<role arn>'
      type: aws     
      requestTemplates:
        "application/json": "<object definition>"
```

To use, I have the following:

```
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
  $ref: '#/definitions/Amazon'
```

On import to API Gateway I receive the following error(s):

Your API was not imported due to errors in the Swagger file.

- Unable to create model for 'Amazon': Invalid model specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid model schema specified. Unsupported keyword(s): ["x-amazon-apigateway-integration"]]
- Additionally, these warnings were found:
- Unknown integration type 'null' for 'POST /'. Ignoring.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using YAML anchors seems like a good idea. The correct syntax is as follows.

Add the following on the root level of your OpenAPI file:

```yaml
x-definitions:      # <--- "x-" before "definitions" prevents it from being
                    #      attempted to be parsed as an OpenAPI Schema object.
  Amazon:
    type: object
    x-amazon-apigateway-integration: &Amazon   # <--- "&Amazon" is the anchor
      responses:
        default:
          statusCode: '200'
      passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
      httpMethod: POST
      uri: >-
          arn:aws:apigateway:<region>:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/<lambda arn>/invocations
      credentials: '<role arn>'
      type: aws     
      requestTemplates:
        "application/json": "<object definition>"
```

Then you can refer to the anchor like this:

```yaml
x-amazon-apigateway-integration: *Amazon
```

However, it might be that AWS parser does not support YAML anchors (`&...`, `*...`). In that case you can try pre-processing your definition using a parser that can resolve YAML anchors and then feed the resolved file to AWS.

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly, and thank you for adding the end paragraph on API Gateway potentially being unable to parse. I did have to run it through https://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv before this would work

Comment: Hey hey, thanks for this. Linking to github thread where I found the same. The key thing is `Metadata` key:
https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/228#issuecomment-564427077

Answer (score 6):

As of 24th April 2020, it appears as though AWS API Gateway does not support referencing `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` components in OpenAPI v3 files, as trying to import the example from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-extensions-integrations.html fails with

```
Your API was not imported due to errors in the Swagger file.
Unknown integration type 'null' for 'GET /'. Ignoring.
Unknown integration type 'null' for 'GET /pets'. Ignoring.
Unknown integration type 'null' for 'GET /checkout'. Ignoring.
```

It looks as though pre-processing the file is currently the only option to avoid repeated integration definitions

Comment: Are you aware of an open issue for this at all? Not being able to reference integrations is a bit shite and increases the amount of configuration linearly.

Comment: Unfortunately this is supported only for HTTP APIs. More info: https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-api-gateway-developer-guide/issues/65

Answer (score 0):

Reading through this thread was a bit confusing for me, so just to clarify, the `x-amazon-apigateway-integrations` object can be used in the `components` section, but just for HTTP APIs, as per [these docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-extensions-integrations.html) (it says "Supported only for HTTP APIs").

For example:

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info":
    {
      "title": "Integrations",
      "description": "An API that reuses integrations",
      "version": "1.0"
    },
  "paths":
    {
      "/":
        {
          "get":
            {
              "x-amazon-apigateway-integration":
                {
                  "$ref": "#/components/x-amazon-apigateway-integrations/integration1"

                }
            }
        },
    "components": {
      "x-amazon-apigateway-integrations":
        {
          "integration1":
            {
              "type": "aws_proxy",
              "httpMethod": "POST",
              "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-2:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:function:my-function/invocations",
              "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_templates",
              "payloadFormatVersion": "1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This makes it easier to use when splitting the spec across multiple files, as YAML anchors can only be referenced within the same file. Of course, if using a REST API there's no other option but to use YAML anchors.