# Use OpenAPI Components with AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, openapi, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am relatively new to AWS API Gateway. I am trying to make use of [OpenAPI Components](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/components/) in the OpenAPI definition for the API Gateway.

I am trying to build reusable responses for the integration response as illustrated below.

This is a reusable component for 400 response (along with the mapping template for it):

```yaml
    components:
      responses:
        BAD_REQUEST:
          statusCode: "400"
          responseTemplates:
            application/json: "#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))\n{ \n  \"message\"\
                : \"Invalid Request Body\"\n}"
```

And I am trying to use this under responses  in the API Gateway Integration like below:

```yaml
          x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
            <API_GATEWAY_CONFIG_GOES_HERE>
            responses:
              .*"BadRequest".*:
                $ref: '#/components/responses/BAD_REQUEST'
```

When I deploy the whole CloudFormation stack I got that error and the stack could not be deployed:

**Unable to put integration response on 'POST' for resource at path '/test_resource': Integration response status code must be non-empty**

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: @Pablo, unfortunately no.

Comment: Did you try YAML anchors?
Although they fall out of the scope of OpenApi and cloudformation but this might fit your case. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53297072/how-to-re-use-my-x-amazon-apigateway-integration-definition-throughout-swagger-y

I am still looking for a better alternative since you will need to run `pakage` command before `deploy` if you use anchors


From aws docs you can try  this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-extensions-integrations.html 
But i haven't been able to get it working though!

Answer (score 1):

I have spent a few days searching for this and the only possible way is YAML anchors:
You can check the code from:

- [How to re-use my x-amazon-apigateway-integration definition throughout Swagger YAML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53297072/how-to-re-use-my-x-amazon-apigateway-integration-definition-throughout-swagger-y)
- https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/228#issuecomment-564427077

Additionally, [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-extensions-integrations.html) official way from AWS doesn't seem to work as of now!